# My virtualhost not working for non-www version

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a development web server (ubuntu + apache) that can be accessed via the url glacialsummit.com.  For some reason, http://www.glacialsummit.com serves pages from the /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/ directory, but http://glacialsummit.com serves pages from the /var/www/ directory.  Here's what some of my virtualhost config files look like

filename: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/glacialsummit.com

```
<VirtualHost 97.107.140.47:80>
     ServerAdmin sovereign@glacialsummit.com
     ServerName glacialsummit.com
     ServerAlias www.glacialsummit.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 97.107.140.47:443>
     ServerAdmin sovereign@glacialsummit.com
     ServerName glacialsummit.com
     ServerAlias www.glacialsummit.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/logs/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.glacialsummit.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.glacialsummit.com.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 97.107.140.47:80>
     ServerAdmin sovereign@glacialsummit.com
     ServerName project.glacialsummit.com
     ServerAlias www.project.glacialsummit.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/project.glacialsummit.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/project.glacialsummit.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/project.glacialsummit.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
## i have many other vhosts that work fine in this file
```

filename /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost 97.107.140.47:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

filename: /etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost 97.107.140.47:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # SSL name based virtual hosts are not yet supported, therefore no
    # NameVirtualHost statement here
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

How do I make http://glacialsummit.com serve web pages from /srv/www/glacialsummit.com/public_html just like http://www.glacialsummit.com?

Comment: Posting (and reading!) the output of `httpd -S` will give you some clues as to the nature of your configuration problem.

Comment: i tried to run httpd, but got a command not found.   i tried apt-get install httpd but go a "Package httpd has no installation candidate".  What library do i need to install use this command?

Comment: It varies depending on distro; on my Debian install the command is: `apache2ctl -S`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the server name of the entire server, outside of any VirtualHosts? I'll bet it's `glacialsummit.com`... If so, then that becomes the `ServerName` for the unnamed VirtualHost in `000-default.conf`, and this VirtualHost overrides the `www.glacialsummit.com` VirtualHost.

Comment: Confirmed!!!  I looked in my /etc/hosts and saw the line "97.107.140.47 glacialsummit.com sovereign".  I changed that line to "97.107.140.47 somethingelse.com sovereign", restarted apache and now glacialsummit.com serves pages from the same place as www.glacialsummit.com!

Comment: Glad I could help. It's often recommended to use a hostname that's different from any websites hosted by Apache, unless the IP will not have any VirtualHosts. So `something.glacialsummit.com` rather than just `glacialsummit.com`

Comment: Legend Josh. Spent quite some time to come to this answer.  Some mail configuration for sending your own mail suggests your hostname should be the same as the domain...this was my issue too.

Answer (score 2):

```
ServerAlias *.glacialsummit.com
```

makes everything, (www, non-www, and subdomains ) fault to the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Under your `ServerAlias` for your top-most virtualhost, add `glacialsummit.com` along with `www.glacialsummit.com`

Comment: I just tried it, reloaded apache, but still the same problem